# how to create a file tree explorer/view using react js?

Tags: reactjs, treeview

I have an react js application whose landing page(index page)  allows the user to create a new folder or new view.

[image]

As seen in the screenshot the folders and views are displayed in the tile view format.I would like to change the view to a tree structure similar to the file explorer seen on ide such as visual studio code or eclipse.

[image]

My render function  for the landing page-

```
  render() {
    const formList = localStorage.getItem("FormList") !== null ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("FormList")) : [];
    const { openmodal, newfolder, foldername, folderList, formView, alertMessage, alert } = this.state;
    const folderid = this.props.history.location.pathname;
    let fid = folderid.replace('/folder/', '');
    return (
      <div className="bacgrounImage">
        <AlertFunction type={alert} msg={alertMessage} />
        <Container fluid>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="12"
              className="spilt folderheader"
            >
              <div style={{ paddingTop: '7px', paddingLeft: '3%' }}>
                <NavLink to={fid === '/' ? "/formcreate" : '/formcreate/' + fid} >
                  <button className='butt' onClick={() => {
                    localStorage.setItem('viewId', null);
                  }} style={{ float: 'right', width: '14%', height: '43px', marginLeft: '10px' }} onClick={e => this.layoutset(e, null, null)}>
                    <h6 style={{ fontWeight: '500' }}>Create New View</h6>
                  </button>
                </NavLink>
                {newfolder === null &&
                  <button className='butt' type='button' onClick={this.folderName} style={{ width: '15%%', float: 'right' }} >
                    <img src={require('./image/newFolder.svg')} />
                    <span style={{ fontWeight: '500' }}>Create New Folder</span></button>
                }
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>File List</h4>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col lg='12' className='newfolder folderList'>
              <div style={{ display: newfolder === 2 ? 'block' : 'none', padding: '8px 8px 16px 1px' }}>
                <span style={{ padding: '6px 18px', cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={e => this.backToForm(e)}><i className="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true" ></i></span>
              </div>
              {(folderList !== undefined && folderList.length > 0) &&
                folderList.map((val, i) => {
                  return <div key={i + "create"} className='list' id={val.id} onDoubleClick={() => this.folderClick(val.id, 1)}>
                    <img src={require('./image/folder.svg')} style={{ width: '48px' }} />
                    <span>{val.name}</span>
                  </div>
                }
                )
              }
              {(formView !== undefined && formView.length > 0) &&
                formView.map((val, i) =>
                  <div key={i + "create"} className='list' id={val.id} onDoubleClick={() => this.folderClick(val.id, 2)}>
                    <img src={require('./image/file.svg')} style={{ width: '48px' }} />
                    <span>{val.name}</span>
                  </div>)
              }

              {
                (folderList !== undefined  && folderList.length === 0 && formView !== undefined && formView.length === 0) &&
                <div className='noDataFound'>No data  found </div>
              }
              {newfolder === 1 &&
                <div className='list' style={{ backgroundColor: '#d3daff' }}>
                  <img src={require('./image/folder.svg')} style={{ width: '48px' }} />
                  <input value={foldername} onChange={e => this.setState({ foldername: e.target.value })} onKeyPress={this.createnewFolder} type='text' style={{ width: '72%', marginLeft: '2px', height: '27px' }} onFocus={this.handleFocus} />
                </div>
              }
            </Col>
            <div lg="12">
              <Formlisting formList={formList} openmodal={openmodal} toggle={this.toggle} />
            </div>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

How do i modify the render function to change the view from the tile view to tree structure view as seen in the screenshot.Plz help?

Answer (score 0):

I would totally use accordions and then list any children into the opening div part. If stumbles upon another folder in a folder, than that's also better be another accordion.